# Можно ли получить количество комментариев одним запросом?

Tags: django, django-orm

Добрый день. У меня есть список новостей и комментарии к ним.
Подскажите как можно оптимизировать запрос

Ниже описаны модельки. Чтобы выбрать новости с разделами одним запросом использую

```
n = News.objects.select_related()
```

А можно ли как то и количество комментариев подтянуть? Не могу понять как правильно можно задействовать `annotate()`

Метод модели `comments_count()` делает слишком много запросов

Пытаюсь как то так выполнить запрос

```
from django.db.models import Count
n = News.objects.select_related().annotate(comment_count=Count('comment'))
```

не помогает, выдает ошибку

**news/models.p**y

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class News(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField()

    def content_type(self):
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=self.__class__.__name__.lower())
        return content_type

    def comments_count(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = self.content_type()
        qs = Comment.objects.filter(object_id=instance.id, content_type=content_type, active=True).count()
        return qs
```

**comments/models.py**

```
class Comment(MPTTModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Object id'))
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    content = models.TextField(max_length=2*1024)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic relations не создают автоматически reverse relations, а потому не могут использоваться в агрегации без добавления поля типа [GenericRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) в модель, которую нужно аннотировать:

```
class News(models.Model):
    ...
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment, related_query_name='news')
    ...


News.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).all()
```

Comment: Помогло, Премного благодарен. Вот ссылка на документацию тем кто столкнется с подобной задачей. https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes.html?highlight=genericrelation#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation